# Jquery onclick, make parent Div invisible

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I have this Jquery :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
       var togClass=$(this).attr('class');
       if($(this).attr('checked')){
          $(this).parent().parent().('div.' + togClass ).css("display", "inline-block");
       }
       else {
          $('div.' + togClass ).css("display", "none");

       }
   });
});
```

and this Html essentially repeated:

```
<div id="Coltext">
     <div id= "Sidechecks">
      <input checkbox class= "ModelName">
     <div id="seqWrap">
     <div id="Nucwrap"> 
     <div id="hit" class= "modelname">"String"</div>
     </div> 
     </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

When i click on the `checkbox` I want the all the `HIT divs` to become invisible, in this Div only.  The main `DIV- coltext` is repeated many times, each has  th e same model, however when the user clicks  on the `checkbox`, I only want the `Hit Divs` for that main div to dissapear, and then reappear on click.  Cant anyone help,It seems simlpe, but i cant get it working ?

Comment: In your html above should 'Coltext' and 'hit' be classes on those divs?

Also remember that you can only use an ID once on a page but a class name can be used as many times as you like.

Comment: yep - i agree with @BillyMoat You should review your markup

Comment: A lot of things are not what it seem to be...

Comment: run your code through a validator - off the shelf, its permitted to write custom attributes only with 4.1 (or lower)  transitional and just for looks, try to keep your HTML in either 100% lowercase - as for attributes in old days, people uses lowerCamelCase most often. Nowadays, in HTML5, everything is lowercase - and custom attributes has 'data-' prefixed, for instance 'data-nucwrap'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See comment about validateable html. Im not sure that `<input checkbox class= ModelName>`
 will render into something selectable by `$('input[type="checkbox"]')`

Try changing

```
$(this).parent().parent().('div.' + togClass )
```

to

```
$(this).parent('div.' + togClass + "[hit]")
```

This should traverse upwards, looking for any DIV with the `togClass` that has parameter 'hit'

Comment: How's it hangin'? Have problems or you got em sorted?

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to check if a checkbox is checked:

```
if($(".myCheckbox").is(':checked'))
{
    // do something
}
else
{
    // do something else
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you fix your HTML mark-up (as per comments above), consider using 'closest', which will search an element and it's ancestors for the closest element matching the selector (rather than all elements matching the selector).

```
$(this).closest('div.' + togClass ).css("display", "none");
```

Your current `else` statement is selecting all matching class nodes.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <div class="Coltext">
   <div id="Sidechecks">
          <input type="checkbox" class="ModelName" />
    <div class="seqWrap">
    <div class="Nucwrap"> 
    <div id="hit" class="modelname">"String"</div>
    </div> 
    </div>
    </div>
   </div>
```

**jquery**

```
$(this).parent('div.' + togClass + "[hit]")
```

Comment: now, that he has changed the attribute 'hit' into 'id="hit"' your copy of another answer will not work..